# Change column values based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Using PowerBI desktop, I have created a small table (called TimeSelector), with three elements: Day, Week and Month

[image: Table example]

The idea is to use the content of this table to create a slicer with three options

[image: Slicer]

Thus, selecting one of those options should change the way dates are used in tables.
For instance, selecting Day would result in the following table:

[image: DayTable]

While selecting Week would result in this:

[image: WeekTable]

Etc..

I have tried to write a new measure taking in account the selected slicer element, but it is not working:

```
DayWeekMonthSelection = IF(CONTAINS(TimeSelector;TimeSelector[DayWeekMonth];"Month");
                           MONTH(VALUES('uptime_downtime'[Uptime_date])))
```

This is only the first part of the formula, only testing the month option as a start.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Bookmarks toggling the visibility of separate tables might better than doing a DAX workaround.

Answer (score 1):

To offer another perspective:

The approach I take with this is to have a separate table in the database - containing meta data about the date, called date_lookup.

2 of the fields in this table are FirstDateOfMonth & FirstDateOfWeek.

Some of the other fields are lastDateOfMonth & LastDateOfWeek, also DayOfWeek.

By using these fields I can easily present visuals that are grouped by month or week.

Sure you can use functions to get this information, but functions can be platform dependant. If you're making a join to the date_lookup anyway - it's no more effort to get this info from there...

The main reason we need to store this meta data is our company Financial year is Jul - Jun.  Therefore we need to have available the Correct FY - which is stored as a field in the date_lookup table.  I also have fields in there identifying public holidays...

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, but I'm not sure how to do exactly what you are asking for, so I'll suggest an alternative. (Changing a measure based on a slicer selection isn't too difficult, but I'm not sure a good way to swap out a field/dimension.)

---

Instead of creating a separate table for your slicers, a different possible approach would be to create a **date hierarchy**. Often when you drag a date column into the rows or columns box it will automatically create a date hierarchy with Year/Quarter/Month/Date, but since you want week and not quarter, let's create one manually.

First, create a couple *calculated columns* for week and month. For example:

```
Month = FORMAT(uptime_downtime[Date], "mmm")
Week = WEEKNUM(uptime_downtime[Date])
```

Now right-click on the date on the fields, and choose New Hierarchy. It should look like this now:

[image: New Hierarchy]

Now drag the `Month` and `Week` columns onto `Date Hierarchy` and then rearrange them in the appropriate order:

[image: Full Hierarchy]

Now you can use that hierarchy in a matrix and use the drill up and down buttons

[image: Drill Up or Down]

to get the different groupings:

[image: Date]
[image: Week]
[image: Month]

Comment: Hello Alexis, Thank you for your answer. This works well, but is not intuitive for end-users. In addition, drill-down functionalities are not available on dashboards, only reports.